# Creating a responsive page with multiple elements - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am new to designing websites using HTML and CSS and I would like to create a page design like the one below:

[image]

As shown in the above picture, the page needs to have a header with a logo, and then two boxes that slightly overlap each other. However, once I did attempt such a design, while it did look good on one screen, I faced a number of problems when attempting to resize the screen such as the squares not moving/resizing to the right position on the new screen.

Below is the code that I have already tried:

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #F1E579;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 350%;
  font-family: Above;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 2.75rem;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 37rem;
  min-height: 40rem;
  left: 7.8rem;
  top: 12.3rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42rem;
  min-height: 45rem;
  left: 44rem;
  top: 10rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when resizing the viewport? Are you looking for the boxes to stay in approximately the same place but resize or to move?

Comment: @Adam I'm looking to have them remain in the same place but expand if larger. But if the page is smaller, I want it to restack in a way that would suit the size (probably into a column rather than a row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the measurement units you use. I have changed the measurement units in the appropriate points from `rem` to `vw` (viewport width).

> 1 `vw` = 1 % of the viewport's width.

This may or may not be appropriate for you, but it achieves the requirement of resizing the boxes (**width only, I left the box heights alone**).

However, this is only a guess and I don't know what you'd like to achieve on mobile screens (phones in portrait view mostly). That definitely requires different styling.

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #F1E579;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 350%;
  font-family: Above;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 2.75rem;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 37vw;
  min-height: 40rem;
  left: 7.8rem;
  top: 12.3rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42vw;
  min-height: 45rem;
  left: 44vw;
  top: 10rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .box1 {
    width: 38vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped heaps. I was wondering, would "%" be similar to "vw" or is the latter better to use in most instances when creating a responsive webpage

Comment: `%` is calculated from the parent element (in this case `%` and `vw` may be the same as the parent element in your case is `body` and the `body` element is as wide as the viewport). If you wish to fit inside the parent element, `%` is better. If you'd like to relate to the viewport, `vw` should be used.